# Adding a dynamically created panel to a Flowlayoutpanel on a user control

Tags: winforms

I'm working on a todo list application and I'm dynamically building a panel from another form based on user input, this said panel is suppose to be added to the flowlayoutpanel on a user control, but nothing is showing up.

Any ideas what might cause the problem.
Update: my code does work if it is executed directly from the user control itself.

My Code

```
private void btnCreateTask_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Panel pnlParentTask = new Panel();
            pnlParentTask.Size = new Size(234, 89);
            pnlParentTask.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            pnlParentTask.Location = new Point(217, 186);

            PictureBox pbFinish = new PictureBox();
            pbFinish.Size = new Size(22, 21);
            pbFinish.Location = new Point(13, 13);
            pbFinish.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            Label lblTitle = new Label();
            lblTitle.Text = txtTaskName.Text;
            lblTitle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            lblTitle.AutoSize = true;
            lblTitle.Location = new Point(41, 12);
            lblTitle.Font = new Font("Arial", 12f);
            lblTitle.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            lblTitle.Tag = lblTitle.Text;
            enc.setpanelTag(lblTitle.Text);
            pnlParentTask.Tag = lblTitle.Text;

            Label lblDescription = new Label();
            lblDescription.Text = txtDescription.Text;
            lblDescription.AutoSize = true;
            lblDescription.Location = new Point(4, 38);
            lblDescription.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            lblDescription.Font = new Font("Microsoft Yahei", 8.25f);
            lblDescription.Tag = lblTitle.Text;

            PictureBox pbPriority = new PictureBox();
            pbPriority.Location = new Point(207, 3);
            pbPriority.Tag = lblTitle.Text;

            pbPriority.Size = new Size(22, 21);
            pbPriority.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

            Label lblDateCreated = new Label();
            lblDateCreated.Location = new Point(3, 69);
            lblDateCreated.Text = txtStartDate.Text;
            lblDateCreated.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            lblDateCreated.Font = new Font("Microsoft Yahei", 8.25f);
            lblDateCreated.Tag = lblTitle.Text;

            Label lblDeleteTask = new Label();
            lblDeleteTask.Text = "-";
            lblDeleteTask.Font = new Font("Microsoft Yahei", 24f);
            lblDeleteTask.Location = new Point(206, 53);
            lblDeleteTask.Click += new EventHandler(lblRemoveTask_click);

            pnlParentTask.Controls.Add(pbFinish);
            pnlParentTask.Controls.Add(lblTitle);
            pnlParentTask.Controls.Add(lblDescription);
            pnlParentTask.Controls.Add(pbPriority);
            pnlParentTask.Controls.Add(lblDateCreated);
            pnlParentTask.Controls.Add(lblDeleteTask);
            priority.flpParent.Controls.Add(pnlParentTask);

            this.Close();
        }
```

Comment: `priority.flpParent.Controls.Add(pnlParentTask);`  Where is that `priority` coming from?  We don't see that.  It's not great programming to have the second form have information about the first form.  Without knowing more, this code block would be a little better if it was a function that returned the `pnlParentTask` and let the first form, which is calling it, add it to its collection.  In other words, the second form shouldn't know about `flpParent`.

Comment: You need to show how the `priority` instance is passed to this *editor* Form. -- This *panel* should be another UserControl, generated internally by the Parent UserControl. You **shouldn't not**, in any case, ever (no matter what code you may find around), change the access modifier of an internal Control (the FlowLayoutPanel, here) to `public` (thus, its internal collection of child Controls). Make a public method, in your top-level UserControl, that accepts those values, generates the new component and adds it to the internal container.

Comment: ```Priority priority = new Priority();``` its a global object of the user control

Comment: @LarsTech it's just a onclick event of a button

Comment: `its a global object of the user control`  Not sure what that means, but it doesn't sound good.  If it's a "new" control, where did you add this instance of it?

Comment: ```public partial class AddTasks : Form
 {
  Priority priority = new Priority();``` I created a global instance of it, it's not local

Comment: So far, you have not shown how `priority` is being used.  It's declared, but it doesn't exist on the screen anywhere.  And it isn't "global".  It's local to the `AddTasks` form.  If you have a `priority` on your first form, you aren't adding anything to it.

Comment: It's an already existing userControl, I'm creating an instance of it to reference the FlowLayoutPanel on it. If I can elaborate, the user control is added onto the main form that will be used throughout the application

Comment: It doesn't work that way.  Your `AddTasks` form has a "new" instance of it.  It's not the one on the first form.  You are adding that panel to a priority control that does not exist on the screen.

Comment: How would I go about fixing the problem

Comment: The fastest way (not the best), is comment out that line `\\Priority priority = new Priority();` in AddTasks, create a local variable in AddTasks `Priority priority` and change your AddTasks constructor to `AddTasks(Priority priority)`  Make sure to include the `InitializeComponent();` line in your constructor, followed by `this.priority = priority;`  You should have a warning in your code that your `new AddTasks` line is missing a parameter.  Use the reference to the existing priority control you have on Form1.  As mentioned, this is poor quality though, but that's a bigger topic.

Comment: I got it working, thanks for the help and my apologies for any confusion

Comment: @LarsTech hey Lars, I continued working on the project and run into a huf, how would I reference different user controls and their components this way without having to add 6 or seven parameters every time I call the form